# Unable to execute file, despite having execute permissions on the file

Tags: permissions

I evidently misunderstand some aspect of file permissions.

I'm attempting to execute a binary file compiled with `g++` within a `/var/www/html/modules` file of a Linux machine from within a Drupal installation:

```
uname -a
Linux <redacted> 3.10.0-1160.6.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Nov 17 13:59:11 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

If I run `ls -al` from within the `modules` directory, I can see that I have full permissions on the file (as the `apache` user):

```
whoami
apache

pwd
/var/www/html/modules

ls -al
total 108
drwxrwxrwx. 42 apache apache  4096 May  8 17:03 .
drwxrwxrwx.  9 apache apache  4096 May  8 16:49 ..
. . .
-rwxrwxrwx.  1 apache apache 46016 May  8 16:38 my_binary

cd ../..
ls -al
total 8
drwxr-xr-x.  4 root   root     33 Dec  3 10:31 .
drwxr-xr-x. 21 root   root   4096 Dec 11 18:49 ..
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root   root      6 Nov 16 16:19 cgi-bin
drwxrwxrwx.  9 apache apache 4096 May  8 16:49 html
```

And here's distro information:

```
cat /proc/version
Linux version 3.10.0-1160.6.1.el7.x86_64 (mockbuild@kbuilder.bsys.centos.org) (gcc version 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Tue Nov 17 13:59:11 UTC 2020
```

For completeness, here's `file` run on the file:

```
file my_binary
my_binary: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), BuildID[sha1]=e7fb75e11b7234dc1129e9502304fcc7440fd788, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, not stripped
```

And, if I check `mount | grep noexec`, the current directory doesn't appear to show up in the results:

```
mount | grep noexec
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,seclabel,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,seclabel)
securityfs on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,seclabel,mode=755)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,seclabel,xattr,release_agent=/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-cgroups-agent,name=systemd)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,seclabel,perf_event)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/memory type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,seclabel,memory)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,seclabel,cpuacct,cpu)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,seclabel,net_prio,net_cls)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,seclabel,blkio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,seclabel,hugetlb)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/pids type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,seclabel,pids)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,seclabel,freezer)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,seclabel,cpuset)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/devices type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,seclabel,devices)
pstore on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
```

And, as suggested in the comments, here's the results of `cat /proc/mounts | grep noexec`:

```
cat /proc/mounts | grep noexec
devpts /dev/pts devpts rw,seclabel,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000 0 0
proc /proc proc rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
sysfs /sys sysfs rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
securityfs /sys/kernel/security securityfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
tmpfs /sys/fs/cgroup tmpfs ro,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd cgroup rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,xattr,release_agent=/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-cgroups-agent,name=systemd 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event cgroup rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,perf_event 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/memory cgroup rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,memory 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct cgroup rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuacct,cpu 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio cgroup rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_prio,net_cls 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio cgroup rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb cgroup rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,hugetlb 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/pids cgroup rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,pids 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer cgroup rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset cgroup rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/devices cgroup rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices 0 0
pstore /sys/fs/pstore pstore rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
```

Despite that, attempting to run the file yields a permissions error:

```
./my_binary
bash: line 84: ./my_binary: Permission denied
```

What is likely to be the issue here, or how can I further diagnose what's causing the permission issues?

---

I feel obligated to say that I ran into this while doing an (easy) Hack the Box challenge. I'm doing the challenges to learn though, and this is a hurdle that I'd really like to learn from.

Comment: @Pourko Thank you. I tried running that, and the results appear to be the same as before. I updated my question with the results.

Comment: Does it really say `bash: line 84: …` when you run just `./my_binary`? Or do you run some script and `./my_binary` happens to be in the script? If the latter then what is the script?

Comment: @Pourko I tried multiple other directories, including `/var/tmp/`, but the results are the same. Most files on the machine are owned by `root`, so I don't have many options.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Yes, the `bash: line 84:` is actually shown. I figured it was because I was in a bash shell, but now that you mention it, it is a bit odd now that I think about it.

Comment: Maybe `my_binary` is supposed to print `bash: line 84: …` and it works fine. :D

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Lol, that would be the simple explanation, but no unfortunately. That line number increments on every command I run (the line number is only shown on permissions errors though). It was up to line 84 because I had apparently run 84 commands before posting this trying to diagnose the problem.

Comment: This is being run from a shell spawned after establishing a Meterpreter session. I didn't think that that was relevant, but it may be due to some internal implementation detail of Meterpreter shells.

Comment: selinux or apparmor or other LSM at play?

Comment: @steeldriver, it's centos and kernel 3.10, so `file` is probably ancient as well and wouldn't report the interpreter. OP has indicated that that bash probably isn't interactive which is why it includes line numbers in error messages (here that most likely the execve() failed with EACCESS)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas ah OK thanks

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I'll admit, my knowledge of selinux/apparmor is very limited. After a quick search though, if I run `getenforce`, it returns `Enforcing`. So there's extra policies in place to prevent execution, on top of file permissions?

Comment: There are tools to notify you if `apparmor` or `selinux` block something. E.g. `aanotify`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the hint from @Stéphane Chazelas, I think I found my answer.

If I run `sestatus`, I get:

```
SELinux status:                 enabled
SELinuxfs mount:                /sys/fs/selinux
SELinux root directory:         /etc/selinux
Loaded policy name:             targeted
Current mode:                   enforcing
Mode from config file:          error (Permission denied)
Policy MLS status:              enabled
Policy deny_unknown status:     allowed
Max kernel policy version:      31
```

So, there are extra protections in place. If I then run `ls -alZ` to show the selinux policies applied to the files, I see:

```
ls -alZ
drwxrwxrwx. apache apache system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_rw_content_t:s0 .
drwxr-xr-x. root   root   system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 ..
. . .
drwxrwxrwx. apache apache unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_rw_content_t:s0 modules
```

I believe the `httpd_sys_rw_content_t` means that only reading and writing are allowed from this file; regardless of file permissions. So, I'll need to find a way around that limitation (or, I'm going in the complete wrong direction).